HTML output on JWT request
I am trying to acquire a token to work with the Salesforce API, but there is something wrong, and I don't understand what exactly. The JWT token was made with the specification https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm, and the token can be successfully deciphered and verified by jwt.io. However, the authentication procedure returns code 200 + HTML instead of a JSON token. I cannot seem to get it to work, although I made the same token via three different packages, and the result is verifiable across all three. Does anybody know why this may happen?
As suggested the code is:
class SalesForceConnection(object):
def __init__(self, base_url, username, client_id, pem_key, access_token_url, pem_password=None,
             token_lifetime=3000):
    self.message_list = []
    self.parameters_dict = {
        '_connection_response_dict_': None,
        '_username_': username,
        '_client_id_': client_id,
        '_access_token_url_': access_token_url,
        '_pem_key_': pem_key,
        '_pem_password_': pem_password,
        '_token_lifetime_': int(time.time()) + token_lifetime
    }

def acquire_token(self):
    claims = {
        'iss': self.parameters_dict['_client_id_'],
        'aud': self.parameters_dict['_access_token_url_'],
        'sub': self.parameters_dict['_username_'],
        'exp': self.parameters_dict['_token_lifetime_']
    }
    
    try:
        
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(self.parameters_dict['_pem_key_'], 
                    password=self.parameters_dict['_pem_password_'], backend=default_backend())
        serialized_jwt = jwt.encode(claims, private_key, algorithm="RS256")
        print (serialized_jwt)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'Error encoding the message: {e}')
        exit(1)

    try:
        response = requests.post(self.parameters_dict['_access_token_url_'], headers={
            'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion': serialized_jwt
        })
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(f'Exception logging into Salesforce: {e}')
        
    response.raise_for_status()
    try:
        self.parameters_dict['_connection_response_dict_'] = response.json()
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        print ('Returned response is not JSON type and decoder failed. Exception is {}'.format(e))
        print ('The content is: {}'.format(response.content))
        exit (1)
    return
# >>>> In the Notebook

sf_connection = SalesForceConnection(base_url, username, client_id, private_key, access_token_url, pem_password=passphrase)
sf_connection.acquire_token()

Again, two different codes - one via cryptography.hazmat, one via JWT library, come with the HTML page instead XML or JSON.
Any help will be appreciated!
Cheers


You should include the code that you're using to post the request to Salesforce (stripping out sensitive info, naturally). You should also look through the html (or are you perhaps seeing xml?) you're getting as a response and double check the response code to see if it actually contains information or if it's something like an error page (the JWT flow requires you to go through a different flow, one that can generate a refresh token like the web-server flow, for the target connected app in your target org before the JWT flow will work).

Also, double check the parameters you're including in the request. If you're providing something for format, that could also explain what you're seeing.

It returns just a Login | Salesforce HTML page - definitely not an XML.

I got it sorted. There were several issues while POST'ing - headers suppose to indicate the content type, data is actually grant + asseertion, and the type has to be url-encoded. Corrected code is:
class SalesForceConnection(object):
def __init__(self, base_url, username, client_id, pem_key, audience, pem_password=None,
             token_lifetime=3000):
    self.message_list = []
    self.parameters_dict = {
        '_connection_response_dict_': None,
        '_username_': username,
        '_client_id_': client_id,
        '_audience_': audience,
        '_pem_key_': pem_key,
        '_pem_password_': pem_password,
        '_base_url_': base_url,
        '_token_lifetime_': int(time.time()) + token_lifetime,
        '_token_url_path_': "services/oauth2/token"
    }

def acquire_token(self):
    claims = {
        'iss': self.parameters_dict['_client_id_'],
        'aud': self.parameters_dict['_audience_'],
        'sub': self.parameters_dict['_username_'],
        'exp': self.parameters_dict['_token_lifetime_']
    }
    
    try:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(self.parameters_dict['_pem_key_'], 
                    password=self.parameters_dict['_pem_password_'], backend=default_backend())
        serialized_jwt = jwt.encode(claims, private_key, algorithm="RS256")
        print (serialized_jwt)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'Error encoding the message: {e}')
        exit(1)

    
    http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 2

    # You must initialize logging, otherwise you'll not see debug output.
    logging.basicConfig()
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
    requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    requests_log.propagate = True
    
    session = requests.Session()
    sending_data = {
        'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
        'assertion': serialized_jwt
    }
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
        
    try:
        request = requests.Request('POST', '/'.join([self.parameters_dict['_base_url_'], 
                                                     self.parameters_dict['_token_url_path_']]), 
                                   data=sending_data, headers=headers)
        prepped = session.prepare_request(request)
        response = session.send(prepped, verify=False)
        
        print (response.content)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(f'Exception logging into Salesforce: {e}')
        
    response.raise_for_status()
    try:
        self.parameters_dict['_connection_response_dict_'] = response.json()
    except JSONDecodeError as e:
        print ('Returned response is not JSON type and decoder failed. Exception is {}'.format(e))
        print ('The content is: {}'.format(response.content))
        exit (1)
    return

It will give a bit more debugging info, but that helps some troubleshooting.
